# Построение гистограммы в python с помощью matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, визуализация

есть такая проблема, нужно вывести результаты программы в виде гистограммы, в excel у меня получается так - как мне нужно, но при построении с помощью matplotlib в python у меня получается по другому, как это можно исправить, чтобы гистограмма была похожа на ту, что строит excel?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В следующий раз приводите текст программы текстом, чтобы отвечающим проще было воспроизводить ситуацию и вносить коррективы в ваш код.

Comment: Вы знаете разницу между гистограммой и столбчатой диаграммой?

Comment: Ваш вопрос скорее всего будет закрыт, потому что вы не привели воспроизводимого примера данных и кода в тестовом виде. а по фотографиям здесь не лечат.

Answer (score 3):

В экселе у вас совсем не гистограмма, а барплот (я толком не знаю, как это будет по-русски, см. комментарий от strawdog), что-то вот такое нужно в `matplotlib` использовать:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

plt.bar([1,2,3,4,5],[-800,-2000,-1000,3000,11000])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]